# Object Icon without tab creation

Tags: tab, style

How to set the object icon for an object without a tab. For those with tabs we do this by setting the tab style. But without tabs is it possible to set the icon displayed on the detail page of such records? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe this is currently possible.

Consider voting for [Assign a color and icon to all objects regardless of tab or not](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpVUAA0)

> I would like to assign colors and icons on an object basis, not just a tab basis. Right now this is called Tab Style. Many times my custom object will show up in a related list or somewhere where I'd like to associate a color and icon, but I don't really want to create a tab for it. In fact, I don't see why we couldn't move the entirety of the Tabs into the Objects themselves - just create a new section under the Object that handles the color, icon, splash page, etc. Since the Tabs are always going to be associated with a custom Object - why not?

Comment: I agree @Daniel , as of now tabs control many aspects of UI and user experience- many features like list views, recent items view etc can only be worked along with a tab.